# Scrapy managing dynamic spiders

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, scrapyd

I am building a project where I need a web crawler which crawls a list of different webpages. This list can change at any time. How is this best implemented with scrapy? Should I create one spider for all websites or dynamically create spiders?

I have read about [scrapyd](http://scrapyd.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), and I guess that dynamically creating spiders is the best approach. I would need a hint about how to implement it though.

Comment: Parsing logic for all of these web-sites is the same, right?

Comment: The parsing logic is the same: I have a number of xpaths in the database. The easy way is just to throw everything in one spider and all parsing in the parse-callback (with a call to the database).

Comment: Yup, sounds like one spider with overriden `start_requests` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If parsing logic is same then there are two methods,

1. For large number of webpages, you can create a list and read that list at the start may b in **start_requests** method or in **constructor** and assign that list to **start_urls**
2. You can pass you webpage link as a parameter to the spider from command line arguments, ans same in requests_method or in constructor you can access this parameter and assign it to **start_urls**

Passing parameters in scrapy

```
    scrapy crawl spider_name -a start_url=your_url
```

In scrapyd replace -a with -d